# How to merge overlapping time intervals if the interval not more than 4 minutes in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

How to merge overlapping time intervals if the interval not more than 4 minutes (for example only where id = 1).

I have the next table:

```
--------------------------------------
id | action    | date
--------------------------------------
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:51:02
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:51:04
2  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:52:14
2  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:52:17
3  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:52:21
3  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:52:24
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:57:21
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:57:22
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:07:56
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:08:56
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:09:11
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:09:11
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:09:11
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:09:13
```

Expected result:

```
--------------------------------------
id | action    | date
--------------------------------------
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:51:02
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:52:24
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:57:21
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:57:22
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:07:56
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:09:13
```

I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Your request is not well defined, because there could be a case in which several adjacent rows can form different merging groups of 4-minutes each, depending on where you draw the start and end time stamps.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL do you use? Please always include it with any questions. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: If you could, the next time you ask a question, put up a fiddle with your data (like I've done [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c08d4277e8a54874ed315e0ac7892c81). It makes life much easier for those trying to help you (less risk of errors and duplication of effort). I did it this time because you're a new contributor, but in future, **please** provide the DDL and DML as a fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, your request is not well defined because it is unclear how the 4-minute wide time windows are supposed to be chosen.
In addition, the nature and importance of the `id` column is unclear.

Be that as it may, I came up with the following query. It uses window functions in order to define the group edges, and then filters out any row that is not an edge:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT id, action, date
         , min(date) OVER (PARTITION BY round(extract(epoch FROM date)/240)) min_date
         , max(date) OVER (PARTITION BY round(extract(epoch FROM date)/240)) max_date
    FROM tab
)
SELECT id, action, date
FROM t
WHERE date = min_date OR date = max_date;
```

Comment: A beautifully elegant solution (+1) - for those who wish to study it, I made up a fiddle  available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c08d4277e8a54874ed315e0ac7892c81)! I had already input the data anyway, so with your solution, the rest was easy!